# Approver getting credit for my edits?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I'm checking on who gets credit for editing other's questions.

I've previously had edits approved for editing a question, and I get the rep.
Today I edited a question for readability and the same edit was approved but it has the name of the approver. As far as I can tell (and I could be wrong) there's no difference to what I suggested other than they (the approver) made some additional pruning.

Does this mean that if a suggested edit is further edited, then the approver making the additional edits gets credit for those changes?

Comment: Which question was it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Mike, I'm the one who approved your [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5370226/revisions). Each item on the "Suggested Edits" page has three buttons: *Approve*, *Reject*, and *Improve*. I felt your edits were good, but the question has a bunch of "fluff" (as Chichiray put it) that cluttered up the question. So I clicked *Improve* and removed those five lines (and made some tag edits). We're both listed in the edit history.

You received +2 rep points (I received none), and we got a better question. We all win. :-)

Comment: Awesome. I found the revisions link (as suggested) and agree with your edits. I'm putting this down to a learning exercise :)

Comment: That's crazy! the editor he's talking about found this question and answered it?! Wild Thornberries if you ask me

Answer (score 6):

The person approving the edit has the opportunity to improve it by making additional changes that build on yours, but you still get the reputation bonus for the approved edit.

Unless, of course, your edit was first rejected and then the reviewer went ahead and made an edit of their own. In which case since they have the rep to edit the post without having to get approval, they will receive no reputation for it.

Answer (score 5):

You each get credit for the changes you make.

Check out the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5370226/revisions) for that question. Your changes are there with your name attached and the approver has a further edit that occurred after yours that removed <strike>the salutation</strike> a bunch of "fluff" and edited the tags, making the post even better.

Comment: It's not only the salutation. There was also lot of other irrelevant fluff/noise :)

Comment: The +2 addition to rep can be seen here:  http://stackoverflow.com/users/567940/mike-hudson?tab=reputation